# What's the English term for this algebra operation?

Tags: terminology

I didn't study maths in English so apologies for this trivial question.

How do you say in English when you have a formula `3n + 3` and you want someone to convert it into `3(n+1)`
I only know about "rearrange" but that's usually about equality, like `U=I*R` can be rearranged to `U/I = R` etc.
Isn't there a more explicit word for this?

For example if I expect `4a - 4b` to be the final result from `2a - 4b + 2a` and someone also does this `4(a - b)`, what would I say?

Replace the end of sentences (those are my guesses):
"I want you to just add polynomials, you didn't have to <segregate the 4>?"
"I want you to just add polynomials, don't worry about <inverse of redistribution>?"

Comment: "Factorize", perhaps?

Comment: The word you are looking for is "factorise" (British English) or "factorize" (US English)

Comment: so will it be
"you didn't have to factorise the 4"? and
"dont worry about factorisation?"

Comment: "don't worry about the factorising" and "you didn't have to take 4 out as a factor"

Comment: Please use 
[MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
to format math on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The operation $$ab + ac = a(b+c)$$ is often called *" factoring out the common factor "*, where the common factor is $a$ here.

> - *" I wanted you to add polynomials, you didn't have to factor out 4 "*
> - *" I wanted you to add polynomials, don't worry about factoring out the common factor "*

---

2. The operation $$a(b+c) = ab + ac$$
   is often called *" expanding the brackets "*.

> - *" If your answer is already factorized, do not expand the brackets "*

Comment: Great thanks! Can you pls confirm factorising as the inverse of factoring out?

Comment: No, the inverse of factoring is distributing. If you are going from a(b+c) to ab+ac, you are distributing the a over the b+c

Comment: @DanielKatz See my addition.

Comment: so good! I'm delighted :-)